# A plane region of area $A$ is inclined at an angle $\theta$ to another plane. Why is the area of the region's projection in that plane $A \cos\theta$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry

How come that $A_1=A_2 \cos(\theta)$?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The area of $A_2$ is being [projected](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_projection) onto the plane parallel to $A_1$.

---

Apologies for the low-effort comment. It wasn't even correct so I'll do it right this time.

Since we're dealing with planes, we can attribute constant normal vectors to each surface $\vec{n}_1$ and $\vec{n}_2.$ Furthermore, we can reduce the dimension of these vectors from $\mathbb{R}^3$ to $\mathbb{R}^2$ by rotating our view of the 3D prism to look only at the 2D front-facing triangle. If we set up a (fairly natural) coordinate system in this view such that $+x$ is in the $\vec{E}$ direction and $+y$ points upwards, then we can have
$$
\vec{n}_1 = A_1
\begin{pmatrix}
1 \\
0
\end{pmatrix}
\ \ \ \ \text{and}\ \ \ \ 
\vec{n}_2 = A_2
\begin{pmatrix}
\cos \theta \\
\sin \theta
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
Vectors represent both magnitude and direction at the same time. It is natural to choose a magnitude that is the area itself and the direction is of course normal to the surface. [Indeed this is just what we do](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_area). Also, the reason we can write these two vectors in $\mathbb{R}^2$ is because the third would-be component is zero for each vector (including it would have no contribution in the projection).

So we wish to project (in the original 3D view) the area $A_2$ onto the plane parallel to $A_1$. In the 2D view, this is the same as projecting the hypotenuse with length $A_2/w$ onto the vertical leg of length $A_1/w$ where $w$ is the width of the prism (into the page). This is done (in 2D) simply (by inspection more or less)
$$
\frac{A_1}{w} = \frac{A_2}{w} \cos\theta.
$$
Really what we're doing here is (in 3D now)
$$
\underbrace{||\vec{n}_1||}_{A_1} = \underbrace{||(\vec{n}_2 \cdot \hat{n}_1)\,\hat{n}_1||}_{A_2 \cos\theta}.
$$

Comment: Is there a reason why the area of the surface is the length of the normal vector? It's not very intuitive.

Comment: @sonny27 That depends on which normal is used. If the normal is calculated from the vectors defining the sides of $A_2,$ which is a parallelogram, then by the fact that $a×b=|a||b|\sin\phi,$ it follows that the length of this normal is the same as the area of the parallelogram.

Answer (score 0):

$A_1$ and $A_2$ are two rectangles, with one side in common (base) and their heights which are leg and hypothenuse of a right triangle. The relation between their areas follows, because the angle between the heights is $\theta$.